# Xmodmad does not run at startup/login

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xmodmap, button-remapping

I put settings in a file called ~/.Xmodmap:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 66=Return'
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
```

The next time I logged in, I was prompted as to whether to load ~/.Xmodmap. I loaded it, and tick “don't ask me again”.

Still it does not remap the desired key. I am using Linux Mint 13 (maya).

The commands work perfectly if I run them manually.

Comment: I have possibly the same issue in Fedora 19.

Answer (score 0):

In the `~/.Xmodmap` file you should only enter the commands, so your file should look like this:

```
keycode 66=Return
clear Lock
```